# Mysql: Look for specific letter in comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I've got a column with the possible `a,b,c` and `city`.

One, many or all of them may occur on each row as comma separated.

**I'm trying to do a query where I look for all rows that contain `c` but not `city`.**

---

I've tried `LIKE %c%` and `LIKE c` but that would not return correct results. I'm starting to look towards Regexp but it feels like there must be a better solution.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `LIKE '%c%' AND NOT LIKE '%city%'`?  That do what you need?

Comment: So you want anything `like '%c% and not like '%city%'`?

Comment: Don't. Normalize your database, comma separated values in a column are almost always an anti pattern.

Comment: @Jack, I've thought of that, but I can't come to think of a better way. That would mostly be due to the fact that I haven't been studying/using sql in years. It's basically a product list and the a,b,c,city would be regions.

Comment: So then you create a `productregions` table to store the relationship between `products` and `regions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for matching comma-separated values:

```
select * from TableName where FIND_IN_SET("c", column)
```

Comment: You get better performance if the column is also of the type SET.